# What is a toric lattice?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, algebraic-combinatorics

What is a toric lattice? and how can I construct one in `Macaulay2` and compute its basis? is there any alternative method to make one? Since I went through the whole documentation of the M2 but could not find anything. For example, we know that a toric lattice of $\dim=3$ is an identity matrix of size 3.

Comment: You might say the context in which you've seen the term, and/or why you want to create them in `Macaulay2`.  Here's what the Magma documentation [has to say](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1804).  In particular, "A toric lattice is a finite-dimensional rational vector space with a distinguished free $\mathbb Z$-module $L$ that spans it: it is the pair $L \otimes \mathbb Q \supseteq L$ where $L$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$."

Comment: This is consistent with the Sage [documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/discrete_geometry/sage/geometry/toric_lattice.html), although that is less explicit about what toric lattices actually *are*.  The point being, I suppose, that there is "only one" toric lattice per dimension, in the sense that all such lattices of the same dimension are isomorphic; but that they are not rigid, in the sense that there are non-identity automorphisms.  I don't know how to square this (har har) with your statement about lattices in dimension 3.

Comment: @LSpice, thanks for the comments. I work on a project that should be done in $\verb|M2|$. I use Magam as well. I am new to "pure combinatorics" and I know little about lattices. In Magma write $\verb|L := ToricLattice(2);|$ and then $ \verb|Basis(L);|$. It is a 2-dimensional toric lattice whose basis is a 2 by 2 id matrix. So, it means that the $L$ is spanned by columns of the id matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.15/share/doc/Macaulay2/NormalToricVarieties/html/_normal__Toric__Variety_lp__List_cm__List_rp.html) of the `normalToricVariety(*,*)` routine (emphasis mine):

> This is the general method for constructing a normal toric variety.
>
> A normal toric variety corresponds to a strongly convex rational
> polyhedral fan in affine space. **In this package, the fan associated to
> a normal $d$-dimensional toric variety lies in the rational vector space
> $\mathbb{Q}^d$ with underlying lattice $N = \mathbb{Z}^d$**. The fan is encoded by the minimal
> nonzero lattice points on its rays and the set of rays defining the
> maximal cones (meaning cones that are not proper subsets of another
> cone in the fan). More precisely, `rayList` lists the minimal nonzero
> lattice points on each ray (a.k.a. one-dimensional cone) in the fan.
> Each lattice point is a list of integers. The rays are ordered and
> indexed by nonnegative integers: $0,1,\dotsc,n$. Using this indexing, a
> maximal cone in the fan corresponds to a sublist of $\{0,1,\dotsc,n\}$. All
> maximal cones are listed in `coneList`.

I'd imagine the other routines either take the same approach or explain it in their documentation.

Comment: thanks! this is I was looking for $\verb| P4 = toricProjectiveSpace 4|$. Then $\verb|latticePoints(polytope (P4_0))|$!